# Union of sets of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am not sure how one should interpret the union of Sets of sets. Is the union a set with the elements being the elements of the sets inside the Sets, or is it a set with the elements being the Sets?

Comment: the latter one.

Comment: It seems you do not agree?

Comment: Okay then, since the other comment disappeared, unless someone says elsewise I will think of the elements as being the Sets. But then 1 is not an element of {(0,1), (2,3)}U{(0,5)} I take it?

Comment: Yes, Emil, you're correct. $1$ is not an element of your union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using plain language here can confuse, so

(1) Interpreting Sets of sets literally, Let $\mathscr X$ and  $\mathscr Y$ be "sets of sets", with $\mathscr X$ = {$X_1, X_2, ..$} and $\mathscr Y$ = {$Y_1, Y_2, ..$} where the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are sets then $\mathscr X \cup \mathscr Y$ = {$X_1, X_2, ..Y_1, Y_2, ..$} and $\mathscr X \cup \mathscr Y$ is a set of sets.

(2) If we are talking about sets of sets generally so that $\mathscr X$ is one such "set of sets" and $\mathscr X$ = {$X_1, X_2, ..$} where each $X_i$ is a set = {$x_{i,1 }, x_{i,2 }, ... $} then you can form the union of the set of sets in $\mathscr X$, notated as $\cup \mathscr X$ = {$x_{1,1 }, x_{1,2 }, ... x_{2,1 }, x_{2,2 }, ...$}

Comment: Yeah I think I needed to understand the literal version. I'd probably just call the latter a union of a set of sets.

Comment: @emil. Both are valid constructions so you just need to be sure which one is indicated in the context you are reading.

Answer (score 11):

Let $A, B, C, D, E$ be sets.

$A = \{0, 1, 2, \cdots 9\}$

$B = \{0, 2, 4, \cdots, 18\}$

$C = \{1, 3, 5, \cdots, 19\}$

$D = \{10, 11, 12, \cdots 19\}$

$E = \{0, 5, 10, 15, 20\}$

Let $P = \{A, B, E\}$ and $Q = \{C, D\}$.

Then $P\cup Q = \{A, B, C, D, E\}$.

Here, the elements of $P, Q$ are sets, so their union is a set of sets (a set whose elements are sets). So their union is ***not*** a set of all the set *elements* contained in $A, B, C, D, E$. (I.e., none of the numbers $0$ to $20$ are in $P, \;Q,\;$ OR $P\cup Q$.)

---

If you want to describe the union of all elements in $A, B, C, D, E$, you would write, e.g., $A \cup B \cup C\cup D\cup E = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 18, 19, 20\}$.

Answer (score 1):

A set (say $X$) of sets (say $A$) is just a set where all of it's elements are sets themselves. Say we are living in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then if we let $X_1=\{A|m(A)=1\}$, then $X$ is the set of all sets with measure $A$ equal to 1.

If we take $\bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+}X_\alpha$, then this union of sets of sets, contains every set $X_\alpha$, which itself contains all the sets of measure $\alpha$.

It would be wrong to say that the elements of the union are all the sets with some positive measure $\alpha$, since the $A$'s are all elements of $X_\alpha$'s themselves. The elements of the union are all the sets of sets $X_\alpha$.

Hopefully this example helps :)

Comment: Oh man. I feel measure theory is going to be very challenging to master if I need to keep this many layers of abstraction in mind.

Comment: @Emil: It will only be hard if you will insist on holding the layers. Instead, let go of the unnecessary "hands on" layers of examples and uses. Work with the definitions, and when need be, apply them to concrete objects. It takes some time to develop this sort of way of thinking, but it ends up quite useful -- not just for doing mathematics, but in general for solving problems.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's true, I don't want it to seem like this is overly complicated. I think measure theory has different types of difficulties :S

Answer (score 0):

> Is the union of a set with the elements being the elements of the sets inside the Sets...

Yes. More precisely, let $F=\{s_1, s_2, s_3, ...\}$ where the $s_i$ are sets. Then $x\in\cup F$ (the union of $F$) if and only if $x$ is an element of *at least one* of the $s_i$.

Likewise $x\in\cap F$ (the intersection of $F$) if and only if $x$ is an element of *every one* of the $s_i$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand this question:

Let us have a set:

A = {1,2,3}
The elements in the set are 1, 2, 3.

To show an element is part of a set, we use the following symbol -> ∈.

For example, 1 ∈ A

Let's say we have two sets, A ={1,2,3} and B = {4,5,6}.

A union is a calculation where you make the sets you are unifying into one.

And yes,

You are talking about the elements. It is basically like addition with whole numbers.

The sign we use is -> ∪ (Not to be confused with U (The universal set)).

Let's get back to our example:

A = {1,2,3}
B = {4,5,6}

A∪B = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

It is important to note if an element is displayed more than once it should be shown once in the union. You would show the union of the sets as (Set 1)∪(Set 2).

One last thing, sets do not have to be used with numbers. They can be used with all different types of information.

I hope you like this answer.